# C macro file naming convention

Tags: c, macros

I would like some advice on naming a C file that contains just macros.

Let's say I'm implementing `struct My_obj`.  A header file would be:
**my_obj.h**:

```
#ifndef MY_OBJ_H
#define MY_OBJ_H

struct My_obj {  
  /* ... */  
};  

void my_obj_do_something( struct My_obj *o );  
/* ... */  

#endif
```

Now, I have a bunch of macros that help to deal with this struct.  *Some* other files might want to use them, but they aren't relevant to everyone and would clutter the header.  I put them all in another file:
**my_obj.macros.h**:

```
#ifndef MY_OBJ_MACROS_H
#define MY_OBJ_MACROS_H

#define MY_OBJ_GENERATE_CODE_1_OF_MANY( OBJ ) \
/* ... */  

#endif
```

The source includes the header and the macros file and uses them to generate actual code:
**my_obj.c**:

```
#include "my_obj.h"
#include "my_obj.macros.h"  

void my_obj_do_something( struct My_obj *o ) {
  MY_OBJ_GENERATE_CODE_X( o );
  /* ... */
}
/* ... */
```

My question is: is this a pattern that appears often, and what is such a macro file typically named? `*.macros.h` looks a bit clunky when I `ls`, so I was wondering if there is a convention for this.  The closest thing I came across is the `.def` extension, but it wouldn't be accurate here since this file does not generate code when included.  Any ideas?

Comment: Using .def might not be a good idea, as that is already used for [dll export definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h.aspx) on Windows.

Comment: The idea is not strange, it does happen. But for the naming issue, why not just `my_obj_macros.h`?

Comment: Why not `my_obj.macros`? Just because the extension isn't .h doesn't mean you can't include it.

Comment: I suggest taking a look on some existing programs out there, or something by your favorite programmer, to take some ideas :-)

Comment: "would clutter the header"? I'm not in the habit of browsing through headers unless there's a clear problem, I prefer to rely on documentation. Hence cluttering is irrelevant. If the macros are related to to other stuff in the header, put them in there.

Comment: Bo: I was referring to .def being used for [X-Macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros), i.e. a header file that generates code when included based on some defines.

Comment: @A.S.H I would prefer my_obj.* over any my_obj_* since on the command line the filename could autocomplete including the period, and not need shift+"_".  The reason I ask is for the same reason that I do not call my header files ".header": it is already understood that ".h" means this.

Comment: @stackptr: Thanks, I like that

Comment: Should I post that as an answer? @FiniteElement

Comment: @stackptr yes, I'll go with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could name the file `my_obj.macro`. Just because the extension isn't `.h` doesn't mean that you can't `#include` it.

Comment: That's likely to confuse tools like cscope, not to mention IDEs and even normal people's typing patterns, when looking for where something is defined. ({{find . -type f -name \*\[ch\] -print | xargs grep SOME_MACRO_NAME}}}. If a file contains C code, don't call it something else.

Comment: Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should. IMHO this is a horrid idea and follows no convention I've seen in use.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix "helper", "utility" or "tools" is often used, like "my_obj_utility.h", or better in a extra directory "utilities".